# How to get xpath and data value from xml schema validation c#

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, xsd

As per our requirements I need to capture the xpath and the  data value for each schema validation issues (errors and warnings). Following is my code- Any help how to get the xpath of the current node and the invalid data value in the xml also if possible line number and data position.

```
XmlReaderSettings readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
            readerSettings.Schemas.Add("http://www.example.com\products", "Schema.xsd");
            readerSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema;
            readerSettings.ValidationEventHandler += new ValidationEventHandler(readerSettings_ValidationEventHandler);
            using (XmlReader xmlReader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(submissionXML), readerSettings))
            {
                while (xmlReader.Read()) { }
            }



 void readerSettings_ValidationEventHandler(object sender, ValidationEventArgs e)
            {
                XmlReader reader = ((XmlReader)sender);
                //can I get xpath and data value from the reader
                //I can get the element name

                if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Warning)
                {
                    Console.Write("WARNING: ");
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
                else if (e.Severity == XmlSeverityType.Error)
                {
                    Console.Write("ERROR: ");
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Exception.LineNumber.ToString() +"-"+ e.Exception.LinePosition.ToString() +"-"+ e.Message);
                }
            }
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12222922/423105

Answer (score 1):

By using the `XmlReader` class, you do not have access to an XPath expression of an element directly.

What you could use out of the box for your code are the `LineNumber` and `LinePosition` properties of [XmlSchemaException](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/system.xml.schema.xmlschemaexception).

Comment: s there any other way of performing schema validation (other than xmlreader) so that I can get the xpath and data value?

Comment: You could try to build the XPath yourself as you read through the XML document, by adding the names etc. of the current element to a stack when a start element is read, and popping it off when an end element is read.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
XmlDocument xdoc = XmlDocument.Load(reader);
var nav = xdoc.CreateNavigator();
XPathNodeIterator navReader = nav.Select("Insert Xpath here");
while (navReader.MoveNext())
{
    var value = navReader.Current.Select("Insert Xpath for Value here");
}
```